# Should I publish in a second rate journal published by a maybe disreputable publisher?

Tags: publications, publishers, disreputable-publishers

I've been invited to write an article for a special issue of an open access journal. According to the prospective guest editor, the editors say that “All papers invited by the guest editor will be published free of charge.”

The journal is published by a publisher that was included on Jeffrey Beall's list (https://beallslist.net/) of predatory open access publishing companies in 2014 but was removed in 2015 following a successful appeal. Nonetheless, criticism of the publisher continues.

I read the Wikipedia article on the publisher and it appears that this publisher maintains a minimum of respectability, even if criticisms continue. But I'm worried about associating myself with a disreputable publisher. On the other hand, I am an early career academic with only two peer-reviewed publications and would like to add more. Should I do it?

Answer (score 8):

Of course not. If you spend the time to write a paper of decent quality, publish it in a journal of decent quality.

If a car salesman invites you to buy a car, would you do so because of the invitation, despite his questionable reputation?

Comment: @Philosopherofscience here you would pay in reputation and in loss of opportunity to publish in a better journal